# Can the SqlDataAdapter refresh itself when the table is changed from an outside source?

Tags: c#, ado.net, refresh, sqldataadapter

My SQL Server table is updated from outside of my program (from a SQL trigger, actually), so the DataSet doesn't realize that there are changes and my DataGrid doesn't update unless I explicitly call SqlDataAdapter.Fill() again (e.g. with a "Refresh" button or a timed event).

Is there a way that ADO.NET can subscribe to change events or such so that it refreshes itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, using [Query Notifications](http://rusanu.com/2006/06/17/the-mysterious-notification/). You get a callback when the dataset has changed and you run your query again.

Comment: Awesome--I'm trying it out now. Thanks!