# Refresh row in datatable

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am using a `DataGridView` to display data from an SQL database.
I working with `datatable` and `bindingsource`.

```
DataGridView grid = new DataGridView();
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(ds);
...
...
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
bs.DataSource = ds;

grid.DataMember = "users";
grid.DataSource = bs;
```

I have problem, when I delete the row on database. This change will not appear in the `DataGridView`. When I edit this row in `DataGridView` I get an error.

It certainly is when you edit the row to SQL Server, but I have in `DataGridView` original data.

How can I solve this problem? 
Thanks

Comment: asp.net or windows application...

Comment: give me delete button code..

Comment: I think this may help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722744/can-the-sqldataadapter-refresh-itself-when-the-table-is-changed-from-an-outside

Answer (score 0):

You will need to update the `DataGridView` via the `BindingSource` (i.e. the `DataTable`/`DataSet`). To do this in your delete event code you will need something like

```
private void DeleteRecord_Click(sender o, EventArgs e)
{
     // Update the database.
     sda.Update(da);
}
```

The `sda.Update(da);` will update the bound `DataSet` and cause the `DataGridView` to subsequently update itself.

I hope this helps.